# Cannot do HAL+JSON Level 3 RESTful API with Spring HATEOAS due to lack of clarity surrounding HAL+JSON media-type

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-hateoas, hal-json

[Level 3](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html#level3) RESTful API's feature custom media-types like `application/vnd.service.entity.v1+json`, for example. In my case I am using [HAL](https://github.com/mikekelly/hal_specification) to provide links between related resources in my JSON.

I'm not clear on the correct format for a custom media-type that uses HAL+JSON. What I have currently, looks like `application/vnd.service.entity.v1.hal+json`. I initially went with `application/vnd.service.entity.v1+hal+json`, but the `+hal` suffix is not registered and therefore violates [section 4.2.8 of RFC6838](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6838#section-4.2.8).

Now Spring HATEOAS supports links in JSON out of the box but for HAL-JSON specifically, you need to use `@EnableHypermediaSupport(type=EnableHypermediaSupport.HypermediaType.HAL)`. In my case, since I am using Spring Boot, I attach this to my initializer class (i.e., the one that extends `SpringBootServletInitializer`). But Spring Boot will not recognize my custom media-types out of the box. So for that, I had to figure out how to let it know that it needs to use the HAL object-mapper for media-types of the form `application/vnd.service.entity.v1.hal+json`.

For my first attempt, I added the following to my Spring Boot initializer:

```
@Bean
public HttpMessageConverters customConverters() {
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(
            new MediaType("application", "json", Charset.defaultCharset()),
            new MediaType("application", "*+json", Charset.defaultCharset()),
            new MediaType("application", "hal+json"),
            new MediaType("application", "*hal+json")
    ));

    CurieProvider curieProvider = getCurieProvider(beanFactory);
    RelProvider relProvider = beanFactory.getBean(DELEGATING_REL_PROVIDER_BEAN_NAME, RelProvider.class);
    ObjectMapper halObjectMapper = beanFactory.getBean(HAL_OBJECT_MAPPER_BEAN_NAME, ObjectMapper.class);

    halObjectMapper.registerModule(new Jackson2HalModule());
    halObjectMapper.setHandlerInstantiator(new Jackson2HalModule.HalHandlerInstantiator(relProvider, curieProvider));

    converter.setObjectMapper(halObjectMapper);

    return new HttpMessageConverters(converter);
}
```

This worked and I was getting the links back in proper HAL format. However, this was **coincidental**. This is because the actual media-type that ends up being reported as "compatible" with `application/vnd.service.entity.v1.hal+json` is `*+json`; it doesn't recognize it against `application/*hal+json` (see later for explanation). I didn't like this solution since it was polluting the existing JSON converter with HAL concerns. So, I made a different solution like so:

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfiguration {

    private static final String HAL_OBJECT_MAPPER_BEAN_NAME = "_halObjectMapper";

    @Autowired
    private BeanFactory beanFactory;

    @Bean
    public HttpMessageConverters customConverters() {
        return new HttpMessageConverters(new HalMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
    }

    private class HalMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter extends MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter {
        public HalMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
            setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(
                new MediaType("application", "hal+json"),
                new MediaType("application", "*hal+json")
            ));

            ObjectMapper halObjectMapper = beanFactory.getBean(HAL_OBJECT_MAPPER_BEAN_NAME, ObjectMapper.class);
            setObjectMapper(halObjectMapper);
        }
    }
}
```

This solution **does not work**; I end up getting links in my JSON that don't conform to HAL. This is because `application/vnd.service.entity.v1.hal+json` is **not** recognized by `application/*hal+json`. The reason this happens is that `MimeType`, which checks for media-type compatibility, only recognizes media-types that start with `*+` as valid wild-card media-types for subtypes (e.g., `application/*+json`). This is why the first solution worked (coincidentally).

So there are two problems here:

- `MimeType` will **never** recognize vendor-specific HAL media-types of the form `application/vnd.service.entity.v1.hal+json` against `application/*hal+json`.
- `MimeType` **will** recognize vendor-specific HAL media-types of the form `application/vnd.service.entity.v1+hal+json` against `application/*+hal+json`, **however** these are invalid mimetypes as per [section 4.2.8 of RFC6838](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6838#section-4.2.8).

It seems like the only **right** way would be if `+hal` is recognized as a valid suffix, in which case the second option above would be fine. Otherwise there is no way any other kind of wild-card media-type could specifically recognize vendor-specific HAL media-types. The only option would be to override the existing JSON message converter with HAL concerns (see first solution).

Another workaround for now would be to specify *every* custom media-type you are using, when creating the list of supported media-types for the message converter. That is:

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfiguration {

    private static final String HAL_OBJECT_MAPPER_BEAN_NAME = "_halObjectMapper";

    @Autowired
    private BeanFactory beanFactory;

    @Bean
    public HttpMessageConverters customConverters() {
        return new HttpMessageConverters(new HalMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
    }

    private class HalMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter extends MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter {
        public HalMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
            setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(
                new MediaType("application", "hal+json"),
                new MediaType("application", "vnd.service.entity.v1.hal+json"),
                new MediaType("application", "vnd.service.another-entity.v1.hal+json"),
                new MediaType("application", "vnd.service.one-more-entity.v1.hal+json")                       
            ));

            ObjectMapper halObjectMapper = beanFactory.getBean(HAL_OBJECT_MAPPER_BEAN_NAME, ObjectMapper.class);
            setObjectMapper(halObjectMapper);
        }
    }
}
```

This has the benefit of not polluting the existing JSON converter, but seems less than elegant. Does anyone know the right solution for this? Am I going about this completely wrong?

Comment: Instead of a custom media type, why don't you use HAL with a profile of your resources instead?

Comment: Why would you include `hal` when you have a more specific media type? It doesn't make sense as `vnd.service.entity.v1` would be based on the `HAL` format per definition. What advantages do you expect by adding `hal` to the media type?

Comment: @JonathanW Could you explain that a bit more? I'm not familiar with using profiles.

Comment: @zeroflagL So are you saying that there's no need to specify that `vnd.service.entity.v1` support HAL from just looking at the media-type? That it should simply be specified in the documentation for that media-type? That idea is certainly appealing. I guess I wanted to make it clear that it was HAL+JSON with additional semantics, from looking at the media-type.

Comment: @VivinPaliath *profile* is a formal parameter to the application/hal+json media type, so it can be expressed without issue.

Comment: @JonathanW Thanks! A few more questions: can it be used for content-negotiation? Is `application/hal+json` with a profile of `vnd.service.entity.v1` semantically different from `vnd.service.entity.v2`? Would it be interpreted as such?

Comment: Yes. Let's assume that you planned to deliver your data alternatively with and without HAL support. Maybe then `vnd.service.entity.v1.hal` is worth to be considered to differentiate between those two. HAL may be(come) a standard but it's more a convention than a format after all. It doesn't say much about your resource.

Comment: @zeroflagL It seems that `profile` is expected to be a URI. So should the URI contain a schema of the JSON? I'm more concerned with the content-negotiation aspect.

Comment: I was referring to my own comment, not to profiles :)

Comment: @zeroflagL Oops got confused :) What you said makes sense. I guess I wanted a way to say "all of these are more-specific subtypes of `application/hal+json`".

Comment: @VivinPaliath Assuming that the request provides the profile parameter in the `Accept` header, then yes. :) If you mean "can Spring MVC support that?" then yes... but it may take a little configuring. See http://spring.io/blog/2013/05/11/content-negotiation-using-spring-mvc

Comment: In terms of a URL for the profile...It certainly doesn't have to point to a schema, but it certainly COULD. I personally favor human readable documentation, because schema is never enough to communicate the interface contract

Comment: Alternatively it could solely be a URI and not point to anything when dereferenced. Much like (dare I say) an XML namespace.

Comment: actually the trick is to use content negotiation on the profile URL too.  So if your request to the profile URL has Accept: application/some.schema.type, you get a response in that schema (if available) and if you ask for text/html you get human readable html doc about that resource profile.  Also when requesting the resource itself you use profile parameter.  IE Accept: application/hal+json; profile=URI

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although this question is a litte bit old, I recently stumbled upon the same problem so I wanted to give my 2 cents to this topic.

I think the problem here is the understanding of HAL regarding JSON. As you already pointed out [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/issues/263), all HAL is JSON but not all JSON is HAL. The difference between both is, from my understanding, that HAL defines some conventions to the semantics/structure, like telling you that behind an attribute like `_links` you'll find some links, whereas JSON just defines the format like `key: [value]` (as @zeroflagL already mentioned)

This is the reason, why the media type is called `application/hal+json`. It basically says it's the HAL style/semantics in the JSON format. This is also the reason that there exists a media type `application/hal+xml` ([source](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html) ).

Now with a vendor specific media type, you define your own semantics and so your replacing the `hal` in `application/hal+json` and don't extend it.

If I understand you right, you basically want to say that you have a custom media type that uses the HAL style for it's JSON formatting. (This way, a client could use some HAL library to easily parse your JSON.)

So, at the end I think you basically have to decide wether you want to differentiate between JSON and HAL-based JSON and wether your API should provide one of these or both.

If you want to provide both, you'll have to define two different media types `vnd.service.entity.v1.hal+json` AND `vnd.service.entity.v1+json`. For the `vnd.service.entity.v1.hal+json` media type you then have to add your customized `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` that uses the `_halObjectMapper` to return HAL-based JSON whereas the `+json` media type is supported by default returning your resource in good old JSON.

If you always want to provide HAL-based JSON, you have to enable HAL as the default JSON-Media type (for instance, by adding a customized `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` that supports the `+json` media type and uses the `_halObjectMapper` mentioned before), so every request to `application/vnd.service.entity.v1+json` is handled by this converter returning HAL-based JSON.

From my opinion I think the right way is to only differentiate between JSON and other *formats* like XML and in your media type documentation you'd say, that your JSON is HAL-inspired in a way that clients can use HAL libs to parse the responses.



**EDIT:**

To bypass the problem that you'll have to add each vendor specific media type separately, you could override the [isCompatibleWith](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/MediaType.html#isCompatibleWith) method of the media type you're adding to your custom `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`

```
converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(
            new MediaType("application", "doesntmatter") {
                @Override
                public boolean isCompatibleWith(final MediaType other) {
                    if (other == null) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    else if (other.getSubtype().startsWith("vnd.") && other.getSubtype().endsWith("+json")) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    return super.isCompatibleWith(other);
                }
            }
));
```

Comment: I like the addition of the new media-type to support my vendor-specific media-types. I more or less arrived at the same conclusion - HAL is just additional semantics on top of JSON, and a custom media-type that uses HAL is your own semantics on top of that. I guess ultimately it just comes down to documenting the media-types and making it clear up front that every resource-representation returned by the API uses HAL semantics. On the code side, providing a custom media-type to recognize your own media-types also makes sense.